# Converting a OneNote page into a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, onenote

I'm working on exporting OneNote documents to SharePoint online with the aim of reducing the overload on OneNote.

My constraint is that I can't convert the OneNote pages to pdf because my sponsor wants the SharePoint search to be able to apply to this information.

I've found that you can export OneNote pages as `.mht` files. Is it possible to convert them into SharePoint pages or text web part?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://natechamberlain.com/2019/01/18/move-an-existing-onenote-notebook-to-sharepoint/

And: https://businesstechplanet.com/how-to-move-a-onenote-notebook-to-sharepoint/

The guides above show how to move OneNote to SharePoint, you can also use the SharePoint Migration Tool, here is MSFT documentation on how to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/migrate-onenote-spmt